# Wordpress admin access and user access with same domain with different A records

Tags: subdomain, wordpress

I am trying use wordpress with multiple server one for admin access and other for user acess, Admin posting will be synced to users server regularly, here I am facing issue with the domains I am trying to have both the sites with same domain ex:- my admin site admin.abc.com and my usersite will be abc.com. All the details I will add through the admin.abc.com and when every user is accessing the they will be viewing it on abc.com for that I will add load balancers and memcache to provide better performance. Have anyone worked in such or else if you have an idea about this please share.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Thanks,
Vela

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I wanted to to seperate the admin and user viewing in different server basic idea is admin posts will be huge in our scenerios that is the core reason behind If i split this I can do cloud load-balancing to the user servers. Also currently I am using hap proxy server that also I can remove using this.